# Hudson build fails with Git repository & Grails

Tags: git, grails, build, junit, hudson

I recently configured **Hudson** to build a **Grails** project using **Git** as the repository. However, I am getting this error when running the build:

```
Compilation error: srcdir "/home/matthew/.hudson/jobs/qotd-idea/workspace/src/groovy" does not exist
```

This is because src/groovy is not copied into the Hudson workspace, so Hudson can't find the files.  However, this directory is empty anyway.  All the valid source files are under the *grails-app* folder.

---

On the flip-side, if I specify the project directory as a full path to my source, JUnit tests are not copied over because I am not using the Hudson workspace:

```
'test/results/TESTS-*.xml' doesn't match anything: even 'test' doesn't exist
```

How do I get both working together?

Comment: If I understand the first part correctly, your git checkout is not creating the directory src/groovy.  I think solving that git issue would be the easiest way of solving your whole problem.   I don't see any likely bugs filed against Hudson yet for checking out empty directories.   Perhaps you can figure out the difference between what Hudson does and what your non-hudson build does, and submit the difference as a bug against the 'git' plugin.

Comment: There is no source code in src/groovy though. There is only source code under the grails-app controller, domain, and views folders. I also tried this Hudson build without Git, using only absolute paths (which built correctly), but got the same message for JUnit.

Answer (score 1):

Hudson looks under the workspace directory for the unit test files.  But the base directory of

```
/home/matthew/dev/source/qotd-idea
```

does not look like a standard Hudson workspace.  Have you set the custom workspace feature for this project?

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I've edited my question to capture the problem more accurately.

Answer (score 1):

To get around the empty folder issue, we normally commit .gitignore to src/grovvy and src/java

I'd recommend doing that instead of pointing Hudson at non-default location.

Have you tried using a full path in the test report location field?

e.g. /home/somedir/qotd-idea/test/results/TESTS-*.xml

cheers

Lee

Comment: I tried that, but Hudson is still looking for those files. I also tried the full path for the unit tests earlier, but Hudson complained that it didn't match anything and didn't exist.

Comment: So you tried using .gitignore files in the two folders and it didn't work? If that's the case then something must be wrong with your git setup.